# StackQL test site updated to March data

Tags: discussion, data-dump, stackql

Last night I updated my [StackQL testing site](http://jcoehoorn.dyndns.org/stackql/) with the March data set.  No other updates were made (it still says "October 2009", for example, and doesn't show any new columns like e-mail hash) and it's still just Stack Overflow data — no Super User, Server Fault, or Meta Stack Overflow yet.  Also, the testing site doesn't have the full-text indexes and it's still on my slow home server and connection.  But otherwise the link is usable with updated data.  Enjoy.

Comment: Is there a reason why the records in the Posts table don't contain tag data?

Comment: @Jon Seigel - Ask Brent Ozar.  I'm still going off of his schema, which normalizes that data into a separate PostsTags table.

Comment: Thank you! Now *at last* I know how close I am to that ever-elusive pundit badge on SO ;)

Comment: Hey Joel, I've failed to tell you in the past how great this is.  So, no more fail.  It's freaking great.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn I've switched to using Sam Saffron's fantastic SoSlow.exe, which imports the XML a heck of a lot faster (despite the wacko name, heh).  http://github.com/SamSaffron/So-Slow

Comment: Voting to close because this tool doesn't seem to exist anymore, and even if that's just my wonky corporate Internet connection, there's probably nothing it can do that SEDE can't do.

Answer (score 2):

Great, I love it!!!

Don't want to nitpick, I'm not sure about how it's in the raw data dump, but I just noted my age is enlisted one off (I'm 18 and am listed as 19). You can try it with the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE  DisplayName='Johannes Rudolph'
```

Comment: That's odd - it lists me as 30 even though I'm still 29.  It shows up correctly on StackOverflow itself.  I don't get DOB data, though; the dump just shows an age field.  Looks like you found a bug with their export - congrats.

Comment: Great, can I buy myself anything for that :-) ? Will file an official request.

Comment: Already done: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/age-calculations-are-wrong-in-the-data-dump-export

Comment: just noticed the moment I hit my browsers return.